# How to add a PHP variable into my Jquery image slider?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a [Jquery Image slider](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/07/slider-gallery/), and I want to add a couple of things to it.

When you load the full-size image, I want to show two divs, one with an image title and the other with a description of the picture but I'm new to javascript and can't work out how to do it.

I have tried adding document.write commands into the javascript code to test it, but this just outputs text on a blank page, where as I want it to appear when the image is loaded and then I can position the divs where I want them.

I would greatly appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery code:

```
   $("img.thumb").click(function(){
    $("#fp_gallery").append("<div/>").text("description");  
    $("#fp_gallery").prepend("<div/>").text("title");
   }
```

Try something like this. This is based on their demo site.

Answer (score -1):

You will be much better off to use jQuery for all of that sort of thing. Look into http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ for what you're after. You may also want to do a bit of research on understanding how the HTML DOM works (http://w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp) to better allow you to work with jQuery and the manipulation tools therein.

Comment: What's your problem? Please don't ever troll SO; this is an intelligent community. kthxbai.